# Cannot change output device after installing Clementine to fix audio

Tags: sound, 20.04, rhythmbox, clementine

Until I installed Rhythmbox and Clementine, I can't play audio from the built-in speakers when I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 (other output devices work, and the built-in speakers work on Windows 10). Now, I can only play audio from the built-in speakers when I'm on Ubuntu, and even when I change the output device, sounds still come out of the built-in speakers. I've even clicked on "Test" in sound settings, and none of the output devices play any sounds. I've even changed the output device in Clementine's playback settings, but that doesn't work. The built-in speakers are from Realtek, and my computer is HP Pavilion.

Do I need to uninstall Clementine and use another fix?

Comment: Do you have other speakers?  How are they connected?

Comment: I've tried connecting my earphones in the headphone jack, which was detected successfully, but the audio still came out of the main speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some tinkering, I've managed to fix the issue, but clicking on "Test" still produces no sounds (I'm fine with that). I'm not sure what exactly fixed the issue, but I've uninstalled Clementine, reinstalled linux-sound-base, alsa-base, and alsa-utils, and installed the package from [OSS](http://www.opensound.com/download.cgi).